# R: iteratively apply some analysis and save the output based on a number used for the analysis

Tags: r, automation, raster

I have 1 raster which I am resampling it multiple times (15 times). Each time I resample it, I am saving the result using as a name the name of the raster and some factor (see the code below). For example, if my raster's name is r, the output, after I resample it using a std of 0.2, should be r2. If the std is 0.25, the output should be r25 and so on. So far, I am doing this resampling manually but I would like to automate the process. Here is an example:

```
library(raster)
r = raster("path/r1.tif")
m = as.matrix(r)
psf = down_sample_image(m,
   factor = 4.66,
   gaussian_blur = T,
   gauss_sigma = 0.2 * 450) # 0.2 to 0.9 with step 0.05
e <- extent(r)
m2r = raster(psf)
extent(m2r) <- e
plot(m2r)
raster::crs(m2r) <- "EPSG:7767"
writeRaster(m2r, "path/r2.tif")
```

The output name of the raster is determined based on the function gauss_sigma. So in the end, I should get the following rasters:
r2, r25, r3, r35, r4, r45......r9.
All in all, I am looking for a repeated process that:
reads the same raster and performs the above analysis 15 times (only the value of gauss_sigma is changing from 0.2 to 0.9 with step 0.05. The *450 should stay the same).
At every iteration, the output should be saved with a name based on the gauss_sigma value.

Here is my attempt (based on the answer below):

```
library(terra)
library(OpenImageR)
        
setwd("C:/Users/Geography/Desktop/multipolygon_test")
    
    
fname <- file.path(tempdir(), "a.tif")
r <- rast(ext(583400, 594200, 1005800, 1025900), res = 100, crs = "EPSG:7767")
values(r) <- sample(46:550, ncell(r), replace = T)
writeRaster(r, fname, overwrite = T)

dsi <- function(m, f) {
  down_sample_image(m,
                    factor = 4.66,
                    gaussian_blur = T,
                    gauss_sigma = 0.20 * 450)
  return(m / f)
}

ff <- c(0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.90)
outf <- paste0(gsub("\\.tif$", "", fname), "_", 1:15, ".tif")
nms <- paste0("f_", ff)
m <- as.matrix(r)

for (i in seq_along(ff)) {
  d <- dsi(m, ff[i])
  m2r <- setValues(r, d)
  writeRaster(m2r, outf[i], overwrite=TRUE, names=nms[i])
}
rast(outf)
```

Here is the output:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 201, 108, 15  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : 583400, 594200, 1005800, 1025900  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Maharashtra (EPSG:7767) 
sources     : a_1.tif  
              a_2.tif  
              a_3.tif  
              ... and 12 more source(s)
names       : f_0.2, f_0.25,     f_0.3,    f_0.35, f_0.4,    f_0.45, ... 
min values  :   230,    184,  153.3333,  131.4286,   115,  102.2222, ... 
max values  :  2750,   2200, 1833.3334, 1571.4286,  1375, 1222.2222, ...
```

The issue is I don't know how to export those raster files. I tried using the `writeRaster` function but I am getting this error (one of my many tries):

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’
```

Any ideas why that might be?

Here is a small raster:

```
r = raster(extent(583400, 594200, 1005800, 1025900), res=100, crs="EPSG:7767")
values(r) <- sample(46:550, ncell(r), replace=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, based on the answer above:

```
library(gridkernel)
library(gridprocess)
library(raster)

tirs = raster("path/tirs.tif")
cr = raster("path/ntl.tif")

for (i in seq(from = 0.2, to = 0.9, by = 0.05)) {
   g = as.grid(tirs)
   smoothed = gaussiansmooth(g, sd = i * 460, max.r = 100)
   r <- raster(smoothed)
   
   raster::crs(r) <- "EPSG:7755"
   
   print(i)
   
  r = resample(r, cr, method = "ngb")
  stringedi = gsub("0\\.", "", toString(format(i, nsmall = 2)))
  file_name <- paste0("tirs", stringedi, ".txt")
  print(file_name)

   # Make sure here you supply full path to folder without the last "/"
   full_file_path = paste0("path", "/", file_name)
   writeRaster(r, full_file_path, format = "GTiff", overwrite = T)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering using "terra", the replacement for "raster"

Example data

```
library(terra)
fname <- file.path(tempdir(), "test.tif")
r <- rast(ext(583400, 594200, 1005800, 1025900), res=100, crs="EPSG:7767")
values(r) <- sample(46:550, ncell(r), replace=T)
writeRaster(r, fname, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I do not have `down_sample_image` but here is simple stub that should be good enough

```
dsi <- function(m, f) {
    return(m / f)
}
```

Define the parameters, create the output file names, and loop over the parameters.

```
ff <- c(1,2,3)
outf <- paste0(gsub("\\.tif$", "", fname), "_", 1:3, ".tif")
nms <- paste0("f_", ff)
m <- as.matrix(r)

for (i in seq_along(ff)) {
    d <- dsi(m, ff[i])
    m2r <- setValues(r, d)
    writeRaster(m2r, outf[i], overwrite=TRUE, names=nms[i])
}
```

Here is the output

```
rast(outf)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 201, 108, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 583400, 594200, 1005800, 1025900  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Maharashtra (EPSG:7767) 
#sources     : test_1.tif  
#              test_2.tif  
#              test_3.tif  
#names       : f_1, f_2,       f_3 
#min values  :  46,  23,  15.33333 
#max values  : 550, 275, 183.33333
```

It looks like your function is wrong

```
dsi <- function(m, f) {
  down_sample_image(m,
                    factor = 4.66,
                    gaussian_blur = T,
                    gauss_sigma = 0.20 * 450)
  return(m / f)
}
```

---

Later:

You do not capture the output of `down_sample_image`. I think it should be

```
dsi <- function(m, f) {
     m <- down_sample_image(m,
                    factor = 4.66,
                    gaussian_blur = T,
                    gauss_sigma = 0.20 * 450)
     return(m / f)
}
```

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer because I am not sure if I can put a code block here on the comments.

Comment: All you should need to do is replace `dsi` with `down_sample_image` and its paramters, and change the values of `ff`, but you add other things, that are not necessary or bad (such as `as.raster`)

Comment: So I managed to run the code without errors but I am having some difficulties while exporting the raster files. I edited my post showing what error I am getting as well as the output (in the console) of your suggestion.

Comment: The data were save to a temp folder, that's why I couldn't find them. But still, the pixel size of the output rasters was the same as the input. This means that, the parameter `factor` from the `down_sample_image` function is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes. see my expanded answer.